# Find the range of $x$ for the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(-3\right)^{n+2}} \frac{\left(4x-12\right)^{n}}{n^{2}+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> **Question:** Find the range of $x$ for the convergence of the series$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(-3\right)^{n+2}} \frac{\left(4x-12\right)^{n}}{n^{2}+1}$$
>   [image: kjn]

**MY Approach:** By $n$th term divergence test,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{\left(-3\right)^{n+2}} \frac{\left(4x-12\right)^{n}}{n^{2}+1}=0 \Longleftrightarrow |4x-12|<1\Longleftrightarrow\frac{11}{4}<x<\frac{13}{4},$$
not in the options.

**Edit**

[image: Cauchy Root Test]

Comment: If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$, that **does not mean** that the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the root test to the above power series. A careful examination gives option $(D)$.

Comment: Sir when you said Root test, you mean Cauchy's root test or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test. Why Cauchy's root test is not applicable here

Answer (score 2):

Using Cauchy root test we have:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{3^{1+\frac{2}{n}}}|4x-12|\frac{1}{(n^2+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{3}|4x-12|$$then for $|4x-12|<3$ the series converges and for $|4x-12|>3$ it diverges. Also for $|4x-12|=3$ we have:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(-3\right)^{n+2}}\frac{\left(4x-12\right)^{n}}{n^{2}+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(-3\right)^{n+2}}\frac{1}{n^{2}+1}$$or$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(-3\right)^{n+2}}\frac{\left(4x-12\right)^{n}}{n^{2}+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{n+2}}\frac{1}{n^{2}+1}$$which converges in both cases. Then the domain is $|4x-12|\le 3\to2.25\le x\le 3.75$

Comment: Sir why you applied absolute convergence test?

Comment: This is what defined by root test I took it form here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test

Comment: I have added my books image

Comment: Then B is true according to my effort...

Comment: Why you did not apply Cauchy's root test?

Comment: This is the same Cauchy's root test!! I proved strict convergence which also implies on convergence of $a_n$....

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(-3\right)^{n+2}}\frac{\left(4x-12\right)^{n}}{n^{2}+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(9\right)}\frac{\left(4-\frac{4x}{3}\right)^{n}}{n^{2}+1}$$
according to Cauchy root test , we get
$$|4-\frac{4x}{3}|\leqslant 1$$
so
$$\frac{9}{4}\leqslant x\leqslant \frac{15}{4}$$